# Embedding more text into the mail body in SMTP Gmail sender

Tags: android

I am using Gmail sender function defined [here](http://davanum.wordpress.com/.../android-send-email-via-gmail-actually-via-smtp/) to send a mail to the predefined mail id. But my problem is that i want to embed more text into the body of my mail... The Gmail sender is only accepting one sting to be embedded into the body of the mail. Can anyone tell me how to embed more strings into the body of the mail... If Gmail sender is not efficient method to send a mail then please suggest me an alternative with an example....

Comment: I am retrieving data entered by user into 4 textviews and a spinner. I want to send all the data entered by the user to the mail. Thats the reason i want to add more string....

Comment: google it. But you can try something like "this" + "that"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably try something like "this" + **"\n"** + "that"